# polygons' ID different from @data ID in a spatialpolygonsdataframe

Tags: r, spatial-data-frame

I loaded a shapefile in R using `readOGR` and I named as `data.map`

I can see the shape pretty well by using

```
plot(data.map)
```

The issue is that polygons' ID (the ID of the plot) is not the same with the `@data` ID.
What I mean is that, when I run:

```
plot(data.map[2, ])
```

and then run

```
data.map@data[2, ]
```

the polygon that is drawn in the plot is not the one that the data row refers to.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if i can delete the question. I found the solution. the problem was that after a merge procedure many of the @data rows were deleted and that resulted to have the ids messed.

Comment: You *can* delete your own question. But I think having your answer here might have value for other users with similar issues.